# date-fns localization does not work as expected

Tags: date-fns

Based on [docs](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/format), I'm tring to show a date in localized formats.

Here's my code:

```
import { format } from 'date-fns'
import { faIR } from 'date-fns/locale'
import { arSA } from 'date-fns/locale'

// rest of the code

                <div>
                    {
                        format(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd', { locale: faIR })
                    }
                    < br />
                    {
                        format(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd', { locale: arSA })
                    }
                    < br />
                    {
                        format(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd', { locale: ru })
                    }
                    < br />
                    {
                        format(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd')
                    }
                </div>
```

One would expect to see different results. But this is what I see:

```
2022/06/22
2022/06/22
2022/06/22
2022/06/22
```

It seems that the localiztion parameter has no effect whatsoever.

And when I change the parameters of the `format` function, all I see is the translation of texts to locales. I don't see a change in calendars. For example Arabic uses Lunar Hijri calendar.

What should I do? Docs are extremely poor in this regards.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fact that you are importing it in 3 different lines could be creating a bug, so I would suggest the following:

To import the corresponding locale in the top of your file:

```
import { ru, faIR, arSA } from 'date-fns/locale'
```

Then, you can safely use it as:

```
format(new Date(), 'yyyy/MM/dd', { locale: ru })
```

Comment: Of course I have included them in the top of my file. Please read the question again.